# Class with whitespace in jade.js templating

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, pug

I'm toying around with jade.js and "Bootstrap, from twitter". Bootstrap has some classes with names that got whitespaces such as "nav secondary-nav".

In jade.js you define a div with div.classname but I can't do it like div.class name, 
anyone knows how I can do this some other way?

Thanks

Comment: Oh, i could just do div(class='what i want here') !

Answer (score 6, accepted):

the class name 'secondary nav' should be 'secondary-nav'

jade syntax would be:

```
ul.nav.secondary-nav
```

example (bootstrap 2.0):

```
div(data-scrollspy='scrollspy').navbar.navbar-fixed
    div.navbar-inner
        div.container
            a(href='/').brand www.sample.com
            ul.nav
                li.active
                    a(href='/') Home
                li
                    a(href='/listing') Listing

            ul.nav.secondary-nav
                li
                    a(href='/account') Account
                li
                    a(href='/logout') Logout
```